# Keep Divs at same height

Tags: html, css, height

I'm trying to figure out how to keep all of the rows the same height. The problem I run into is that when they have no content they shrink down to just the padding height.

The full example can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/c85ajj9a/

Code snippet:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="col-md-1 detail-box leftcolumn-bold">Co-Bor 1:</div>
                                    <div class="col-md-1 detail-box">Maria</div>
                                    <div class="col-md-1 detail-box">Smith</div>
                                    <div class="col-md-2 detail-box">699, 685, 675</div>
                                    <div class="col-md-1 detail-box">$6,500.00</div>
                                    <div class="col-md-2 detail-box email-text">maria.smith@gmail.com</div>
                                    <div class="col-md-2 detail-box">714-555-5555</div>
                                    <div class="col-md-2 detail-box">626-555-5555</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="col-md-1 detail-box leftcolumn-bold">Co-Bor 2:</div>
                                    <div class="col-md-1 detail-box"></div>
                                    <div class="col-md-1 detail-box"></div>
                                    <div class="col-md-2 detail-box"></div>
                                    <div class="col-md-1 detail-box"></div>
                                    <div class="col-md-2 detail-box email-text"></div>
                                    <div class="col-md-2 detail-box"></div>
                                    <div class="col-md-2 detail-box"></div>
                                </div>
```

Comment: It's obvious you are using Bootstrap, but you are using it wrong. "col-xx-y" classes can only be inside "row" class. Now you have "col-md-x" inside "col-md-12". This may work improperly in some browsers.

Comment: I understand that. I only posted a small portion of the code in the snippet. The full section is in the jsfiddle. 

Thanks for the detailed look though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a min-height will add the height to the rows even if there is no content.

```
.detail-box {
    padding: 5px;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    text-align: center;
    font-size:18px;
    color:black;
    min-height:18px;
}
```